# iOS - Swift - Loop for with array and condition

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'm looking for doing a loop on an array but want to stop after a condition. This is what I have now (btw, I'm using Parse as back-end).

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "MyObject")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects {
                print(object.objectId)
            }
        }
}
```

This code is printing every objectId.

Now let's imagine I want to print every object **until** my find an object with `objectId == "xxx"`.

How should I do that?

Comment: you can return or break out of the loop. if objectId == "xxx" { break/return }

Comment: Does Swift not have the concept of break?  That's the standard method of escaping from a loop in most languages.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to filter objId and perform some code:

```
let array = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"]
for objId in array where objId != "id3" {
    print(objId)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `filter` is what you're looking for

```
let objects = [["id": 1], ["id": 2], ["id": 3]]
objects.filter { $0["id"] != 3 }.forEach { print($0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 for object in objects {
            print(object.objectId)

      if object.objectId == "xxx"
       {
         // object Name is found
         // if you like to break the execution use "break"
         //break
        }
       else
        {
          // object ID not found
        }
      }
```